# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x3)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Hi I am getting the following error from this code:

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x3)
```

When I press play I am basically looped back CFRetain.

I can't figure out what's the problem with this.

XCode is pointing specifically at this line:

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[self getCorrectName:oldController], @"ViewController", sec, @"duration", nil];
```

I checked both values of the dictionary and they seem to check out.

[image]

```
- (NSString *)getCorrectName:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if (viewController.class == [UINavigationController class]) {
        UIViewController *vc = [viewController.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        return NSStringFromClass(vc.class);
    } else {
        return NSStringFromClass(viewController.class);
    }
}

# pragma mark - UITabBarControllerDelegate

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tbController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    // Tracking which controller will be clicked
    [[Mixpanel sharedInstance] track:@"tab_clicked"
                          properties:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [self getCorrectName:viewController], @"ViewController", nil]];

    // Tracking how long was spent on the last controller
    UIViewController *oldController = [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:self.selectedIndex];
    if (viewController != oldController) {
        NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [self.start timeIntervalSinceNow];
        NSInteger sec = -1 * (secondsBetween + 0.5);          // round up and down
        if (sec > 0) {
            NSLog(@"Changing controllers from %@, %d seconds", [self getCorrectName:oldController], sec);
            [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[self getCorrectName:oldController], @"ViewController", sec, @"duration", nil];
            /*
            [[Mixpanel sharedInstance] track:@"tab_viewed"
                                  properties:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                              [self getCorrectName:oldController], @"ViewController", sec, @"duration",
                                              nil]];
             */
            self.start = [NSDate date];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It indicates a clobbered pointer.  In your case it's probably because you're passing an NSInteger as a pointer.  (Hint:  Don't do that!)

Comment: NSDictonaries cannot contain non-objects (or they will crash when they try to retain its value).  Wrap `sec` in an NSNumber.

Comment: Yes, despite its "NS" prefix, NSInteger is *not* a class

Comment: The red flag in this case should be the address 0x3.  I don't think applications are ever allowed to write to such a low address.  If it happens again you should immediately say "Oh, it looks like an int is getting interpreted as a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

NSInteger is NOT a class.

Use NSNumber